# How can I press a key for a given amount of time in advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I am writing a voice command using Advanced Scripting in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate).

I know that I can send the key using `SendKeys`, `SendSystemKeys` or `SendDragonKeys`, e.g.

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

Is there any way to specify how long I want the key to be pressed (e.g. maintain  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for 1.5 second)?

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-press-a-key-for-a-given-amount-of-time-in-advanced-scripting